submenu de no se despliega en blazor net 8
Estoy experimentando con el menu de Blazor Wep App. He probado con Webassembly y con Auto en el rederizado
He creado este menú con un submenú
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Gestion</a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" />

<div class="nav-scrollable" onclick="document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').click()">
  <nav class="flex-column">
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
      <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
        <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
      </NavLink>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item px-3">
      <NavLink class="nav-link" href="weather">
        <span class="bi bi-list-nested-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Weather
      </NavLink>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item px-3">
      <NavLink class="nav-link" href="auth">
        <span class="bi bi-lock-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Auth Required
      </NavLink>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-item px-3 dropdown">
      <NavLink class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle"  @onclick="()=>expandSubNav=!expandSubNav">
        <span class="bi bi-lock-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span>Admin
      </NavLink>
      @if (expandSubNav)
        {
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
          <NavLink class="nav-link" href="device">
            <span class="bi bi-lock-nav-menu"></span>Sub-menu 1
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
          <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
            <span class="bi bi-lock-nav-menu"></span>Sub-menu 2
          </NavLink>
        </div>

        }
    </div>
   </nav>
</div>

@code {
  private string? currentUrl;
  private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
  private bool expandSubNav = true;

  private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

  private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
    collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
    }

  private void OnLocationChanged(object? sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    currentUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(e.Location);
    StateHasChanged();
    }

  public void Dispose()
    {
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
    }
}

Y no consigo que el submenú se despliegue y/o se oculte. Ese mismo código funcionaba en net core 7 wasm.
El problema creo que está en está línea  @onclick="()=>expandSubNav=!expandSubNav" que no ejecuta el onclick.
Alguién sabe por qué?
Saludos

Por si a alguien le interesa.
Dos posibilidades

Añadir interacción con el servidor con está línea al principio
@rendermode InteractiveServer

Crear el en proyecto del cliente las carpetas:Components -> Layout y dentro mover los archivos NavMenu.razor  y NavMenu.razor.cs y luego en el archivo Components -> Layout -> MainLayout.razor hay que decirle que el menu está en el proyecto del cliente.


Esto señores de MS haciendo la vida cada vez más sencilla.
